# mobile event with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery to make a div appear when the users moves their mouse or makes a keypress.  I would like to add something similar for mobile users, .i.e. when they touch their phone's touch-screen.

I was reading [this article](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/api/events.html) and wonder if I need to add a tap event to my code like this:

```
jQuery(document).bind('mousemove keypress tap', function() {
    jQuery('.mk-nav-responsive-link img').fadeIn();
    userInactivity = 1;
```

At the moment I'm using jQuery v1.11.0

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend "touchstart" event.

Comment: so I would use `jQuery(document).bind('mousemove keypress touchstart', function() {` ?

Comment: Yes, exacly like that.

Comment: is jQuery v1.11.0 enough or would I need to include jQuery mobile also?

Comment: You don't need jquery mobile. :)